# Summernote editor, angular - issue with tooltips background

Tags: angular, tooltip, summernote

I have problem with the tooltips in my summernote component:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see on the picture, tooltip background covers only the part of the whole tooltip. This occurs with all the tooltips in the summernote. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: This is cause of `overflow: hidden` property on CSS

Comment: Maybe you can try with a `position: absolute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by updating summernote to the latest version.